# In-place upgrade from WSS 3.0 to SharePoint 2010 failed

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, wss-3.0, wss

How can I do a rollback after a failed SharePoint upgrade? Or If anyone knows how can I get the upgrade back on track, please advise.

Many thanks

Comment: What failed? It's not possible to correct the failed installation rather than rollbacking (if possible)?

Comment: Please provide more information on the situation, it may be resumed or it may have terminally failed. Only way is to restore the server to how it was preupgrade. Hopefully you might have taken a snapshot of the web front end server and a full set of DB backups. If so then please revert to your snapshot and restore the databases.